Show BOTH the base cage AND the subdivided mesh
I'm trying to follow some chair design tutorials and I see it in every single video: they're somehow able to tab into EDIT MODE and view the solid mesh with a subdivide modifier with the BASE (not-subdivided) cage on it.

I searched the internet far and wide and I can't seem to find the combination to do this.
I'm on 4.2.1 LTS.
I tried "optimal display" checkbox, "wireframe" option in overlays, and the small controls near the subsurf modifier on the modifier stack.
My scene always looks like this: Either i'm viewing the base cage, OR the subdivided model.
Is there an extension/plugin for that that nobody mentions in their videos?
thanks!
EDIT: This is how my scene looks after applying the wireframe overlay:


Enable Wireframe in the Viewport Overlays panel:


I already mentioned I did that. The viewport stays the same and shows the subdivided cage instead of the base one.

Oops ok sorry...

I had a Normals > Smooth By Angle modifier on top of my stack with the On Cage turned on. I turned off On cage and it's all good now.
